# Proper casting of the object in C++, value field is not changing

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a class:

```
class Para{
public:
    int wrt, liczbaWystapien;
    Para(){}
    Para(int wrt, int liczbaWystapien){
        this->wrt = wrt;
        this->liczbaWystapien = liczbaWystapien;
    }
```

Then there is other template class, and I do not know how to cast object to `Para`, becuase first way does not affect field value at all.

```
           else if (is_same<T, Para>::value){
        //dynamic_cast<Node<Para>*>(node)->key.wrt++;//this way no error occured but value of field **wrt** stays the same
        node->key.wrt++;//error below
```

`Error  4   error C2039: 'wrt' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>`'

EDIT:

Node* paraNode =  static_cast*>(node);
        Para para = paraNode->key;
        para.wrt = para.wrt + 1;

That gives

Error
4   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'Node *' to 'Node *'

Answer (score 1):

Something seems weird, because key's type supposed to be Para. What happens if you spell everything out?

```
Node<Para>* paraNode = dynamic_cast<Node<Para>*>(node);
Para para = paraNode->key;
key.wrt = key.wrt + 1;
```

Other suggestions: if fore some reason you are sure about the template type, you can use `static_cast<>` (or `reinterpret_cast<>`), it's faster than `dynamic_cast<>`, which really discovers and check the type hierarchy tree.

Comment: Thank you after changin to static cast I got error, please look at edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you do 
`Para para = paraNode->key;`

you get a copy of the key. Then you increment wrt. If you do a printf following that line, you will probably get the expected value. However if you call this from inside a function then the original paraNode will not be modified.

You need to store key as `Para* key` then access `key.wrt` with `key->wrt++` then after the function you will get the expected value. I suggest you read on how stack and heap variables work as well as copy constructor in c++